# can we say that pumps are carriers that need ATP?

Tags: biochemistry

I know that pumps always use ATP , but i don't know what is the relationship between carriers and pumps .
are pumps a subdivision of carriers ?

Comment: see WP [membrane transport protein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_protein?wprov=sfti1.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can consider pumps are carriers used for active transportation (needing ATP).

A carrier is a specific type of transport proteins. They differ from channels or pores in the fact that during a certain instant, carriers only have one side of the protein open<sup>[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_transport_protein#Difference_between_channels_and_carriers)</sup>. While pores are continuously open, and channels are either open or closed<sup>[2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_transport_protein#1:_Channels.2Fpores)</sup>.

Carriers can be involved in active transport<sup>[3](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_transport_protein#Active_transport)</sup> or facilitated diffusion (passive)<sup>[4](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_transport_protein#Facilitated_diffusion)</sup>. But as you mentioned, pumps always are used for active transport. Pumps, as Bryan pointed out in the comments, are just a name given to some transport proteins that use active transport, but not all active transport proteins are labeled as pumps.

I hope this clarified things for you.

Comment: Not all pumps use ATP. Some things named pumps use ion gradients. It's not very precise terminology.

Comment: Would a more precise terminology be to remove "that use ATP to function" and replace it with active transport? As ion pumps using gradients would be using secondary active transportation.

Comment: Yeah. I think the optimal answer would also address that "pumps" aren't a special protein category, just a naming convention for some proteins involved in active transport. Other proteins with nearly identical function are known by other names, like "transporters", without an obvious defining characteristic (that I am aware of). That is, all pumps use active transport, but not all active transporters are given the name "pump". Those that use ATP directly, like Na/K pump, are also known as "Na/K ATPase" etc.

Comment: thank you for your answers ;
     
but i have another question ; 1- can we say that all pumps do a kind of active transport but don't need ATP , 2- can you give me an example of one transporter that do active transport but isn't a kind of pump ? – user35622 47 secs ago   edit

Comment: 1- All pumps do active transport, but not all use ATP to power ([secondary active transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_transport#Secondary_active_transport)). 2- An example of a whole family of active transporters the don't use "pump" are the ABC Transporters ([Wiki - ABC Transporter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP-binding_cassette_transporter))